# Restarting a script in Python

Tags: python

I'm wondering how I can restart a script without just calling the function itself. You can see the example below. After "two" is printed I want the script to restart itself without just calling one().

```
import time
zero = 0

def one():
    global zero

    for i in range(50):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        zero += 1
        print(zero)
        if zero == 10:
            two()

def two():
    print("two")
    #Restart the script

one()
```

Comment: What do you mean by restart? What state are you expecting? What behavior?

Comment: Put the function call in a `while` loop. Such constructs are covered by tutorials

Comment: if you want it to "restart" after printing "two", why is it inside a loop? Maybe what you mean is `if zero % 10 == 0:`?

Comment: I need this example for an other script but it's too hard to explain with my English. I just want the code to stop after print("two") and restart everything again. I'm looking for something like os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, * sys.argv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do some condition forever, so the most practical way is to use a while loop with a condition that is always true.

```
while True:
    one()
```

You probably also want to return from function `one` after calling `two`

```
if zero == 10:
    two()
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a `while` loop,

```
import time
zero = 10
i = 0
while i <= zero:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        zero += 1
        print(zero)
        print("two")
```